# how to keep user logged in

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

this is how I login using Google and firebase. but I couldn't figure it out as to how to keep the use logged in.. when the app restarts it log the  user out automatically

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount!.authentication;
  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );
  final authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final User? user = authResult.user;
  assert(!user!.isAnonymous);
  final User? currentUser =  _auth.currentUser;
  assert(user!.uid == currentUser!.uid);
  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `await _auth.currentUser()` at the start of your app to check the current user. Further you may want to store the token in shared preferences.

Comment: could you show me in code please? @RodrigoBustillos

Comment: currentUser() has not been a Future in a long time (two years?).  You want just `FirebaseAuth.currentUser`

Answer (score 0):

Firebase automatically persists the user credentials in the shared storage, and restores them when the app restarts. There's nothing you need to do for that.

What you *will* need to do though is listen for the authentication state as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#get_a_users_profile):

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user != null) {
      print(user.uid);
    }
  });
```

This code needs to run when the app starts, so I typically have it in my top-level widget and then store the `user` in the state so that my `build` method can use it. By listening to auth state changes, the code is run automatically when the user sign-in state is restored at startup (which happens asynchronously, so may take a few moments) but also when the user would later be logged out (for example, if you disable the account in the Firebase Authentication console).

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best way to do it but this worked.

```dart
chooseLogin() {
  if (_auth.currentUser == null) {
    return const SignUo();
  } else {
    return const Splash();
  }
}
```